# I can not read the uplodade file from App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to upload and read some text files in my app. I have `[file, setFile]` in my App.js . I want to upload a file from homepage.js and keep it in the `file`. When I want to check file in homepage.js with `console.log(file)` I see null:

[image: Here is the output]

I need some help about that. If you need more info about code just ket me know. Thanks.

Here is my App.js file:

```
function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState(null);
  const [convertedFile, setConvertedFile] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage file={file} setFile={setFile} />} />
          <Route path="convert" element={<Convert file={file} setConvertedFile={setConvertedFile}/>} />
          <Route path="download" element={<Download convertedFile={convertedFile}/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>  
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my homepage.js file:

```
function Homepage(props) {
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.setFile(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
        console.log(props.file);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row style={{marginTop:"15vh"}}>
                    <Col>
                        <h1>Homepage</h1>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row style={{marginTop:"10vh"}}>
                    <Col>
                        <p style={{border:'1px solid black'}}>This tool fixes Turkish character issue on your subtitle files</p>
                        <div>
                            <Form >
                                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                                    <Form.Label>Upload your file</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control id="file" type="file" />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Button onClick={handleSubmit} variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
                            </Form>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

            </Container>
        </div>
    )
```

Here is my convert.js file:

```
function Convert(props) {
    console.log(props.file);
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row style={{marginTop:"15vh"}}>
                    <Col>
                        <h1>Converting...</h1>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row style={{marginTop:"10vh"}}>
                    <Col>
                        <ProgressBar animated now={100} />
                        <div id="file">
                            aa
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem myself. It was about sync code. When I try to `console.log(props.file)` actually there is a `props.file` const in my App.js but because of the execution time It seems null. Because as I understand js starts executing the next code line before current line execution ends. Actually `props.file` gets the value that I want but js logs it before the assignment. I used await and fixed it

Comment: The reason is because you are attempting to read `file` when react's state has not been updated: remember that the React state is not updated immediately but is batched.